# Change sheet source dynamically

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office-interop

How to change Excel sheet source dynamically depending on particular values?
I am developing an Excel sheet. Depending on one dropdown value, fields of other dropdown should change dynamically.

Suppose I choose one value from dropdown1, dropdown2 should get certain column from  "Sheet2" and if I choose another value from dropdown1, dropdown2 should get certain column from suppose "Sheet".

How can I achieve this?

This should be related to Excel formulas I guess.

Comment: Did you try [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=make+drop+down+list+dynamic+excel)? There are many tutorials to do this,  Many youtube videos that will walk you through step by step.

Comment: @Sanjay did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Just follow [this](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dependent-drop-down-lists.html) tutorial

1. Create lists
2. Give lists a name
3. Use data validation to create dropdown
4. Use indirect when creating new data validation