# How can I reset a dynamically changing validation list to the first item?

Tags: excel, vba, list, validation, reset

I m using the following code to dynamically change a validation list in Excel. The idea is that when an other value changes then the list should, for example, contain three items instead of five (the first two are gone):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim ToS, CoC As String
Dim HoC, HoR As Single

ToS = Range("B4").Value
CoC = Range("B12").Value
HoC = Range("B10").Value
HoR = Range("B11").Value

With Range("B6")
    With .Validation
        .Delete
        If ToS = "CMSA" Then
            If HoC <= 7.6 Then
                If HoR > 10.7 Then
                    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                    xlBetween, Formula1:="=$V$3:$V$3"
                Else
                    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                    xlBetween, Formula1:="=$V$1:$V$3"
                End If
            ElseIf CoC = "III" Or CoC = "IV" Then
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                    xlBetween, Formula1:="=$V$3:$V$3"
            Else
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                    xlBetween, Formula1:="=$V$1:$V$3"
            End If
        ElseIf ToS = "ESFR" Then
            If HoR > 10.7 And HoR <= 12.2 Then
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                    xlBetween, Formula1:="=$V$7:$V$9"
            ElseIf HoR > 9.1 And HoR <= 9.8 And HoC > 6.1 And HoC <= 7.6 Then
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                    xlBetween, Formula1:="=$V$6:$V$7"
            ElseIf HoR > 12.2 And HoR <= 13.7 And HoC > 7.6 And HoC <= 12.2 Then
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                    xlBetween, Formula1:="=$V$7:$V$9"
            Else
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                    xlBetween, Formula1:="=$V$6:$V$9"
            End If
        Else
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                    xlBetween, Formula1:="=$V$6:$V$9"
        End If
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

The problem is that I want it automatically to be reset to the first item of the list. The list is getting the data from some other cells in a row in the same sheet.

How could I do that?

What do I need to add to the code?

I tried adding after the `...formula1:=` command something like `Range("B6").Value= "the value I want"` but it does not work.

Comment: This is likely possible without using VBA at all - are you using VBA for a different part of your project? Because avoiding it here could be useful if it meant the workbook was macro free. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31948083/5090027 for an example of how to do this without VBA.

Comment: A non vba answer was given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33697154/change-sheet-source-dynamically).  Just this morning I might add.

Answer (score 0):

Although I would have to agree with Grade 'Eh' Bacon & Scott in their comments, I think what is being sought is simply something like the below:

(That is I think you just want to add a line to change the value to be the first value in the data validation list)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim ToS, CoC As String
Dim HoC, HoR As Single

ToS = Range("B4").Value
CoC = Range("B12").Value
HoC = Range("B10").Value
HoR = Range("B11").Value

With Range("B6")
    With .Validation
        .Delete
        If ToS = "CMSA" Then
            If HoC <= 7.6 Then
                If HoR > 10.7 Then
                    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                    xlBetween, Formula1:="=$V$3:$V$3"
                    .Value=Range("$V$3").Value
                Else
                    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                    xlBetween, Formula1:="=$V$1:$V$3"
                    .Value=Range("$V$1").Value
                End If
            ElseIf CoC = "III" Or CoC = "IV" Then
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                    xlBetween, Formula1:="=$V$3:$V$3"
                    .Value=Range("$V$3").Value
            Else
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                    xlBetween, Formula1:="=$V$1:$V$3"
                    .Value=Range("$V$1").Value
            End If
        ElseIf ToS = "ESFR" Then
            If HoR > 10.7 And HoR <= 12.2 Then
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                    xlBetween, Formula1:="=$V$7:$V$9"
                    .Value=Range("$V$7").Value
            ElseIf HoR > 9.1 And HoR <= 9.8 And HoC > 6.1 And HoC <= 7.6 Then
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                    xlBetween, Formula1:="=$V$6:$V$7"
                    .Value=Range("$V$6").Value
            ElseIf HoR > 12.2 And HoR <= 13.7 And HoC > 7.6 And HoC <= 12.2 Then
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                    xlBetween, Formula1:="=$V$7:$V$9"
                    .Value=Range("$V$7").Value
            Else
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                    xlBetween, Formula1:="=$V$6:$V$9"
                    .Value=Range("$V$6").Value
            End If
        Else
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                    xlBetween, Formula1:="=$V$6:$V$9"
                    .Value=Range("$V$6").Value
        End If
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

But again I think you would be better off handling the data validation as they suggested, and maybe just using the vba to change the cell's value.